# What does number+enter do in Explore?

Tags: filesystem, netrw

as we know that we can use Vim to browse a directory. My question is what does <kbd>number + Enter</kbd> do on a file list?
I thought it equivalent to <kbd>number + j + Enter</kbd>, however, after I enter into a file, using `:b#` leads me to another "unpredictable" location.

Eg, suppose we have `/A/B/f1 /A/B/f2 /A/B/f3 /A/C/f4 /A/C/f5`.

When I enter into folder A from Vim and the cursor is on `../`, what will happen if I type <kbd>2 + Enter</kbd> or <kbd>3 + Enter</kbd>? When a file is open, what will happen when I type `:b#` in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: [`:help netrw-cr`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-cr) does not document any use of the count. Most attempts I have made result in `Invalid range: call s:UseBufWinVars()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> binding of netrw is documented in the [`netrw-cr`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pi_netrw.html#netrw-cr) help section. It mentions nothing about any use of the count.

I suspect the count is simply "falling through" to an internal function of netrw that is not prepared to handle it. Most of my own attempts resulted in the error message `Invalid range: call s:UseBufWinVars()`, and those that didn't did not form any recognizable pattern, though I did notice ending up in directories that were multiple steps away from the one that I had been browsing.

Calling it with a very large count like 100 results in many instances of the same error message, suggesting something is being executed a number of times corresponding to the count.

Comment: Thanks, but what does "netrw-cr" mean? And what does "netrw" stand for?

Comment: netrw is the plugin that handles directory browsing with Explore, its help topics have a prefix of `netrw-`, and cr refers to the carriage return key (enter). It's called netrw because it also handles reading and writing files over a network.